# Google Cloud Storage - Upload an 'Object' without using Google Client

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, json-api

I've been looking around for the past few days for an answer to this question, but I haven't been able to find the solution I'm after.

I have a fully working version of doing this task using Google_Client, however I want to be able to do this without using the Google_Client. I can create buckets without using it, but not Objects. I cannot understand the [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) on this at all (it's pretty poor).

So, I have a function below which takes in several parameters to *try* and upload a file. I'm not sure what needs to go in `$authheaders`, `$post_fields` (the body of the post) or the url.

```
public function upload_file($bucket, $fileName, $file, $fileType) {

        // Check if we have auth token
        if(empty($this->authtoken)) {
            echo "Please login to Google";
            exit;
        }

        // Prepare authorization headers
        $authheaders = array(
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->authtoken
        );

        $postbody = array();

        //Http call for creating a file
        $response = $this->http_call(self::FILE_UPLOAD_URL.$bucket.'/o?uploadType=multipart&name='.$fileName, $postbody, $authheaders);

        // Has the file been created successfully?
        if($response->success=="1") {
            return array('status' => 'success', 'errorcode' =>'', 'errormessage'=>"", 'id' => $response->job->id);
        }
        else {

            return $response;
        }
}
```

The http_call function:

```
public function http_call($url, $post_fields, $authheaders) {

        // Make http call
        $this->httpRequest->setUrl($url);
        $this->httpRequest->setPostData(json_encode($post_fields));
        $this->httpRequest->setHeaders($authheaders);
        $this->httpRequest->send();
        $response = json_decode($this->httpRequest->getResponse());

        return $response;

}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples#env ?

Comment: Yes. But it uses the Google Client, which I don't want to do. I already have a working version using Google Client, but I'm now trying to do this task without it.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw json api documentation for insert object? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

Comment: I have done, but I don't really understand it. Not sure what goes in the post body or headers part out of that, OR where the file is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is looking to do this without using the API, here is how I solved my question using curl.

```
// Prepare authorization headers
        $authheaders = array(
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->authtoken,
            "Content-Type: application/pdf"
        );

        $url = self::FILE_UPLOAD_URL.$bucket.'/o/?uploadType=multipart&name='.$fileName.'';

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $authheaders);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Goole Cloud Storage PHP Starter Application google-api-php-client/1.1.5");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        // 1 is CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1, which is not always defined in PHP.
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```